# Организация кода js

Tags: javascript, jquery, структуры

Есть функция :

```
$(function run($) {
  $('.i').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('.m').toggleClass('m-open');  
  });
}(jQuery));
```

Хочется организовать код, например:

```
(function($) {

/* Glob  */

  (function() {
      window.a = {
      button_toggle: $('.i'),
      menu: $('.m'),
      m_open: $('.m-open'),
      newMenu: $(this.button_toggle).on('click', function(){
      $(this).closest(a.m).toggleClass(a.m_open);
      })

  };
  })();

})(jQuery);
```

данный вариант не работает (((

Comment: " вариант не работает" - еще бы! что Вы думаете такое `this.button_toggle` в момент создания `window.a`? И что возвратит `$(this.button_toggle).on('click' ...`?

Comment: конечно не работает, ты же в первом случае ждешь конца построения DOM, а во втором - нет. Второй вариант заработает, если ты расположишь его перед закрывающим тегом body

Comment: @Igor, я даже на знаю каким дубликатом лучше закрыть :) про потерю контекста или поискать что-то про время выполнения

Comment: @Grundy да-а-а, дилемма!

Comment: Если ты заменишь `$(this.button_toggle)` на `$('.i')` то все заработает если перенесешь код в конец документа

Comment: подозреваю, что `а.newMenu` будет не тем, на что надеется автор

Comment: @Igor , тоесть что нужно сделать чтобы заработал код?)

Comment: @расположил после тэга боди , всеравно не работает

Comment: "не работает" - что это значит? Что оно должно делать, чего не делает?

Comment: @Igor оно должно создавать новый класс `.m-open`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  window.a = {
    button_toggle: $('.i').on('click', function(){
      $(this).closest(a.menuSelector).toggleClass(a.menuOpenClass); 
    }),
    menuSelector: '.m',
    menuOpenClass: 'm-open'
  };

});
```

```css
.i {
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color:red;
border:1px solid black;
}

.m {
padding:25px;
background-color:yellow;
border:1px solid black;
}

.m-open
{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="m">
  <div class="i"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не работает!   `вызов button_toggle()` не работает

Comment: И не должен. Это не функция. В Вашем вопросе никакого вызова `button_toggle()` нет. Объясните, что Вы пытаетeсь сделать.

Comment: Есть элемент на странице **<div>**, который представляет из себя бургер меню, и при нажатии на область элемента<div>, хочу доавить обработчик события 'click', чтобы добавить новый класс `m-open`, содержащий в себе  иные  значения стилей для визуальной анимации , что на кнопку нажали

Comment: @ВладимирВладимирович Очень хорошо. Теперь, пожалуйста, про вызов `button_toggle()`.

Comment: вызвал функцию,а разве так нельзя вызвать функцию ?) вообщем  мне нужно вызвать button_toggle, чтобы обработчик начал свою работу

Comment: @ВладимирВладимирович Это не функция. http://api.jquery.com/on/ Это объект-обертка воркруг набора элементов с классом `i`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68704/discussion-between---and-igor).